# Infinite scroll in django

Tags: django, django-pagination, django-endless-pagination

Is it possible to implement facebook style loading of content while scrolling down? I would like to implement it in an ecommerce site. There are a lot of items in each category and the category page becomes too long. I could implement page numbers but my client wants me to implement that facebook type of loading. Is there anything I can use? Rest of the site has already been built.

I did look into django-endless-pagination but was not able to get it to work. Is there any demo of it so that I can look into it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We used django endless pagination on www.mymommemories.com without too much problem. Because we were using html5media we did have to add a line to run that function with a one second delay. (setTimeOut("html5media()", 1000). Running it without the delay caused problems in some browsers. If your not using html5media, this should not be a concern however.

Core part of the template code.

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate memories %}
{% for memory in memories %}
.
.
.
{%  endfor %}
{%  show_more %}
```

In the view we have the following to handle the ajax request.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    template = page_template
    return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The page_template is not the whole page, just the portion related to the "paging".

Comment: When using class-based views, you must specify self for the request object.  `if self.request.is_ajax():`

Answer (score 2):

I thinks the easiest way to do endless pagination is use jQuery (use $.loads).
You even don't need change the back-end code.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Perhaps take a look at that?