# How to load more content in Django application?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, scroll

I have developed a template for viewing the group list in my Django application. What I came to know is that, after more groups, the page is scrolling down. I am unable to see all the names of the groups. Also, I want to view only 4 group names at the start and then after clicking the load more button, the next 4 groups show up. I am unable to do this.

```
    {% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}
{% block pregroup %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="content">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>
            Welcome back
            <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">@{{user.username }}</a>
        </h2>

    {% endif %}
            <h2>Groups</h2>

            <p>Welcome to the Groups Page! Select a Group with a shared interest!</p>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'groups:create' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create New Group!</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block group_content %}
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for group in object_list %}
          <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug %}">
                 <h3 class="title list-group-item-heading">{{ group.name }}</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
                {{ group.description_html|safe }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.members.count }}</span> member{{ group.members.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.posts.count }}</span> post{{ group.posts.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}

                    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to add a scrolling option to this page. How to do that? Pagination could be a solution. But I want to load the list on the same page itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite scroll in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382196/infinite-scroll-in-django)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Parse the object_list into a JSON object:** This should allow you to provide the client with all the groups that exist in order to achieve your goal to keep the user on the same page.

**2. Use jQuery or Javascript to refresh your html container that has the groups listed:** Based on the size and type of data, you can also write a new view that returns a filtered JSON object to a post method in Javascript.

Example: https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH

```
    /*
     Load more content with jQuery - May 21, 2013
    (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
    */   

$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```